# When to use DocumentChange.Type of ADDED, MODIFIED AND REMOVED?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I aware this question is too general, for the specific i have a code below that implement `DocumentChange.Type.ADDED`, and **work when i add new data** as follow:

```
firestore.addSnapshotListener...
    for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

         if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {                               

             MyContent content = doc.getDocument().toObject(MyContent.class);

             myList.add(content);
             myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                

          }
    }
```

my specific question is, when to use `DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED` do you guys have examples code?

Comment: Asking for code samples is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok, and what should i do?

Comment: You haven't really indicated what the problem is you're trying to solve.  Your question is just saying "when to use DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED".

Answer (score 1):

You use it to check if a document that was previously in the result set is not longer in the result set.  If you don't care about that case, then you don't need to use it.

Comment: it sounds that i have to refresh my recycler.